# How to make function callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new in javascript hence this might sound a little weird question, I have a class CreateApi that has a property

```
this.createNew(id,successcallback,errorcallback)
```

I return values on the successcallback of this function

```
successcallback(values)
```

I have another class in which I create an object of CreateApi

```
var t = new CreateApi
```

Then I do

```
t.createNew(id,function(values){
 // do something },function(e))
```

I want to define the successcallback function somewhere else so that I can use this successcallback function for more than one properties of CreateApi how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the function as normal.

```
 function someFunction(values) { }
```

Then pass it as the argument.

```
 t.createNew(id, someFunction)l
```